# ../github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:166752:10: fatal error: 'unicode/utypes.h' file not found

Tags: go, sqlite

Mac, Linux共に下記エラーになります。

`go build --tags "icu"`

> # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
>   ../github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:166752:10: fatal error: 'unicode/utypes.h' file not found

以下補足情報です。

`go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/m7258/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/d2/y6ws0ldx5vn5tk1h5h5cjxhh0000gn/T/go-build482302534=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

`cat main.go`

```
package main

import (
        "database/sql"
        "log"
        _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
        db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Linux に関して言えば、`libicu-dev`(Debian系)か `libicu-devel`(Red Hat系)をインストールする必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

質問者です。コメント追加できないため、回答からコメントします。

解決しました。
metropolisさん、mattnさんありがとうございます。

OS: Mac

```
brew install icu4c
brew link icu4c --force
```

参考
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259191/installing-libicu-dev-on-mac

OS: Linux(Debian)
`apt-get install libicu-dev`

Comment: [ここ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2092/間違えて作成したアカウントを統合-マージ-リンクする方法はありますか/2093#2093)を参照してアカウントのマージを行なってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。マージしました。

Answer (score 1):

go-sqlite3 を icu 付きでビルドするには、ビルド対象向けの icu ライブラリをインストールしておく必要があります。